# Is CSS3 grid layout in experimental Web Platform package working in Dartium v34?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, dartium

In the upgrade from Dartium v33 to v34.0.1847.0 (with Web Platform enabled), the layout of the grid based on the [CSS3 Grid Layout Module 1](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-grid/) specification in our application stopped correctly allocating the vertical free space. I implemented the example 1 [(gist)](https://gist.github.com/wjfl/17a0a6a43a3aedf3d8cd) from the spec to investigate and found that the middle row is not flexing as expected. Am I missing something or is this a bug? If this is a bug, is there a workaround other than fixing the height of the flexible space? Several of our custom polymer.dart components depend on grid-layout.